# How do the various methods of roasting beef compare?

Tags: beef, roasting

I can think of 3 ways to roast beef:

1. Rotisserie Oven
2. Regular Oven
3. BBQ

What are the pros and cons of each?

Comment: Voting to close; at this point, recipe requests are considered off-topic (see http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/4/should-i-need-a-recipe-for-x-questions-be-off-topic).

Comment: also subjective etc.

Comment: Is this a recipe request?  I can't answer it that well myself since I don't make a lot of roast beef, but surely there are noticeable differences in tenderness, moistness, savoriness and other characteristics when using the different methods?  I must admit that I don't entirely understand the downvotes and close votes here.

Comment: Seems like this is a cooking method question.  What type of appliance do you use to roast your beef and why?

Comment: Whether or not it's a recipe request, it's a "List of X"-type question, so it should still be closed.

Comment: Edited out the "best" part - obviously that's a personal decision. Still, this question might be more useful if it was more direct: *"How does roasting beef in a rotisserie compare to doing so in a regular oven?"* - busy defending an edit elsewhere though; if that interests you Pyrolistical, consider deleting this and re-posting.

Comment: I think the revised question is much better!

Answer (score 3):

A roast is a roast is a roast.

Roasting is a method of cooking that involves the aplication of a lot of dry heat to a peice of meat. You can obtain a great roast from all the above the cooking methods as long as you take into account the various ways they work.

A rotisserie offers all around even heat and will remain juicy although you can lose some juice from the skewer through the center, but may not cook the roast as perfectly as you lack good tempature control.

The oven is a great way to roast meat as long as you use the two tempature method.  That means you start high and finish low or vice versa.  I tend to side with Alton Brown on this and start low (normally 200 but you can adjust according to time requirements) until my roast is ~25-to-20 degrees of medium rare, pull it out and bring the oven to 450, put back in and remove to rest at 15 degrees short of desired doneness.  You also have to make sure that you raise the roast off the bottom of the pan because if you don't you will end up braising the roast in it's own juices.

Your grill can work as long as you keep the lid closed and the roast from directly over the coals, but it is going to be the method that needs the most constant attention and will be easy to end up with a overdone outside and a underdone interior.